# Excel 2013 (32 bit) VBA Scripting.FileSystemObject.DIR not listing all files

Tags: excel, vba, directory, filesystemobject

I have created an excel application that listed all files in a selected directory (in Excel 2013 32 bit). Following is the script

```
Const path_col = 1;
Const PDF_File_Col = 2;

Sub input_file(zipFile As String)

Dim source As String
Dim FileCount As Integer
Dim FileName As String
Dim fso
Dim currentPDF As String
Dim currentTXT As String
Dim currentrow As Long
Dim first_Date_Created As String
Dim Cur_Date_Created As String
    

Dim CurSheet As Worksheet

Set CurSheet = ActiveSheet

    

source = Replace(zipFile, ".zip", "\")
FileCount = 0
currentrow = Sheets("List").Cells(4, 1).Value
FileName = Dir(source, vbReadOnly)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If Right(FileName, 3) = "pdf" Then
            Cur_Date_Created = Format(fso.getfile(source & FileName).datecreated, "yyyy-Mmm-dd")
            
            currentPDF = FileName
            
            With Sheets("List")
                .Cells(currentrow, path_col).Value = source
                .Cells(currentrow, PDF_File_Col).Value = currentPDF
                
            End With
'            read_file source & currentTXT, currentrow
            currentrow = currentrow + 1
        End If
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Exit Sub
```

**Issues**

The script have been running daily since few years ago under Windows 7 without any issue until moving the Windows 10 a few months ago. After moving into Windows 10 we start finding it failed to list all pdf files (ie. stopped in the middle so how) intermittently without any error message populated (Note: we have not dismissed any error message before running this subroutine.)

The PDF files inside the folder was named by consecutive number and always end with ".pdf" (always in lower case). For Example:  If the folder have 1200 PDF file, it will then be in arange as "PDF0001.pdf", "PDF0002.pdf" - "PDF1200.pdf". However, for some reason the sub-routine may stop running at "PDF0900.pdf"and the rest ("PDF0901.pdf - "PDF1200.pdf") will be missed from the list. However, it mayworks fine if we simply rerun the subroutine.

**Note**

1. User selected the zip file. However, it was already unzipped before
   enter to this subroutine The folder only have pdf files. But usually
   have more than 1000 to 5xxx and the total folder size can be upto 500MB

Could you please share me some light on what should I do regarding to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. The folder does  not have **only pdf files**, since the folder path is extracted from a Zip one, but this is not an issue since the retrieved files by `Dir` are filtered according to their extension.
2. If you move the first `Dir` **after** `source = Replace(zipFile, ".zip", "\")` it will be better. Only in this way the folder path is a correct one.
3. Try transforming it in `fileName = Dir(source & "*.pdf")`. In this way, it will return only the pdf files in the directory and you can comment the line `If Right(FileName, 3) = "pdf" Then`, not being necessary, anymore.
4. `Dir` does not belong to `FileSystemObject`.
5. I (only) suppose that not `Dir` is 'guilty'. It correctly retrieves all files until the code crushes. Try using `DoEvents` after the line `FileName = Dir()`. And maybe after, too...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru,

1. The folder specified in the source path is 100% only have pdf file. Nothing else

2. Apologies, it was a typo while preparing this blog  it is right, it was originally after the replace command, it was typo by mistake

3. Will try. Thanks for your advice

4. Thanks for correction

5. Using DoEvents()?? Could you please explain in more detail? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @E Leung: 1. I cannot understeand that, since the folder path is extracted from a Zip file located there... 5. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function), please. When the code writes to the worksheet, some events are triggered (Selection_Change, Worksheet_Change, Calculate etc.). For a lot of files to be processed, Excel (maybe) needs a break to process all of that before starting the next loop... :) Try it and see what happens! Anyhow, it will not harm anything...

Comment: Agree. No harm at all. Will try.

Comment: BTW, eg. zip file name “c:\temp\myzip01.zip”, when extracted, the extracted file (where the source stores) will become “c:\temp\myzip01\” while the zip file remains in “ c:\temp\myzip01.zip” and all pdf files from the zip file will be extracted under the “myzip01\” folder. (Note: source will become “ c:\temp\myzip01\”)